# Log snapshots fail on instance in VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a rails application using AWS Elastic Beanstalk, with the web server instance and RDS instance in a private subnet in the default VPC. The web server instance is connected to a publicly accessible load balancer.

For some reason, when I try to snapshot the logs, it spins for a moment like it's collecting them, but then nothing ever shows up in the snapshot list. Is it possible to get the logs from an instance in a private subnet, or do I need to rethink my setup?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "snapshot the logs".

Comment: When I go into the Elastic Beanstalk console and hit the Snapshot Logs button.